# Convert array of objects to plain object using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How can I convert an array of objects to a plain object?
Where each item of the array is an object with only one key:value pair and the key have an unknown name.

I have this

```
const arrayOfObject = [
    {KEY_A: 'asfas'},
    {KEY_B: 'asas' }
]
let result = {} 
const each = R.forEach((item) => {
   const key = R.keys(item)[0]
    result[key] = item[key]
})
return result
```

But I dislike that solution because the `forEach` is using a global variable `result` and I'm not sure how to avoid side effects here.

Comment: If I could give you 10 points for using RamdaJS I would... :+1:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ramda has a function built-in for this, [`mergeAll`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll).

```
const arrayOfObject = [
     {KEY_A: 'asfas'}
    ,{KEY_B: 'asas' }
];

R.mergeAll(arrayOfObject); 
//=> {"KEY_A": "asfas", "KEY_B": "asas"}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since everybody is using ES6 already (`const`), there is a nice pure ES6 solution:

```
const arrayOfObject = [
  {KEY_A: 'asfas'},
  {KEY_B: 'asas'}
];

Object.assign({}, ...arrayOfObject);
//=> {KEY_A: "asfas", KEY_B: "asas"}
```

`Object.assing` merges provided objects to the first one, `...` is used to expand an array to the list of parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use reduce instead:

```
const arrayOfObject = [
     {KEY_A: 'asfas'}
    ,{KEY_B: 'asas' }
];
const each = R.reduce((acc,value) => { 
   const key = R.keys(value)[0];
   acc[key] = value[key];

   return acc;
},{},arrayOfObject);
```

Since your array is an array of objects, you could also just call merge inside a reduce:

```
const each2 = R.reduce((acc,value) => R.merge(value,acc),{},arrayOfObject);
```

Here is a jsbin with both examples:
http://jsbin.com/mifohakeru/edit?js,console,output

Comment: reduce() is a very helpful suggestion, especially for more complicated cases.